# php not updating mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a cron job that executes php script daily and sends an email. I've added a simple update part to the end of the script to change status of rows to 1 when the email was successfully sent.

Here is the not working part of the code:

```
<?php

// ...working part of the code

if(!$mail->Send()) {
       $conn->close();
}

else {
       $update = '
         update history set EmailStatus = 1
        ,EmailSent = NOW()

        where
        EmailStatus = 0
        and DeliveryDate <= CURDATE()
        ';
    echo 'email sent';

    $conn->close();
}
?>
```

What doesn't work is the update part. It doesn't update the table. SQL code is working when I run it directly on the server, so the sql statement is not a problem. I am not closing the connection anywhere before in the code. Any ideas what I've missed?

Comment: Have you tried actually executing the update statement (in your PHP code)?

Comment: Yes, update statement itself works outside php.

Comment: But you don't run it in your PHP code.

Comment: So far, this is a typographical error that was made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't use the query function to execute your query

```
$update = 'update history set EmailStatus = 1,EmailSent = NOW() where EmailStatus = 0 and DeliveryDate <= CURDATE()';
$conn->query($update);
$conn->close();
```